# Free will and hard determinism

Tags: free-will, determinism

Can we say that **hard determinism** and **free will** are mutually exclusive by definition?

Comment: Yes, 'hard determinism' is the term associated with incompatibilism (the view that the world is either deterministic or we have free will but not both). The term 'soft determinism' is used in the context of compatibilism (the view that both determinism and free will can/do exist).

Comment: Assuming "free will" means something beyond "the illusion of free will," then yes, we can and we should precisely for the reason you specify. so what's the question we can answer for you about philosophy?

Comment: In order to say they're exclusive, you first have to precisely define free will.  Good luck with that.

Comment: @kbelder  You don't need a definition of B if X is defined as "either A or B, exclusively", and you have asserted A.

Comment: @jobermark That's a bit circular, though.  If your definition of free will is 'anything not deterministic', then yeah, the answer is clear.  That's not a great definition, though, because that means 'free will' and 'pure randomness' are one and the same.

Comment: @kbelder  Applying a stated definition is not circular.  The position of hard determinism is what its adherents say it is.  Whether or not they are making sense is beside the point.  You can argue against their position being tenable, but that does not change the position itself.

Comment: Mea Culpa.  I'm arguing the wrong point due to misreading the question.  I don't disagree that they are mutually exclusive, but I was hung up on those two choices not being exhaustive.  There are theories which deny both free will and determinism, so it's not a simple binary option.

Comment: Could it be that both  **hard determinism**  and **free will**  are false?

Comment: @Snochacz I think the straightforward materialistic interpretation of quantum mechanics may reject both.  It is non-deterministic... there's randomness in every interaction.  However, many people wouldn't consider simple randomness as actual free will, either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. However, I respectfully disagree with Not_Here's characterization of Hard Determinism; "Hard Determinism" is used to refer to the view that endorses the following conjunction: 1) Incompatibilism about Free Will and Determinism is true and 2) Determinism is true. It follows from (1) and (2) that no one has free will. So, Hard Determinism is mutually exclusive with any view that claims people have free will (e.g. typical versions of Compatibilism/Soft Determinism and Libertarianism).

Comment: When I said "'hard determinism' is the term associated with incompatibilism (the view that the world is either deterministic or we have free will but not both)," the parenthetical clause was meant to explain what "incompatibilism" means, not what "hard determinism" means. Incompatibilism says that one of those disjuncts is true and the other is not, hard determinism says the first is true and libertarianism says the second is true. That I what I wrote, which I believe you have misunderstood.